# How do you isolate nested dependencies in PHP?

Tags: php, dependencies, dependency-management, isolation

I have three files, **foo.php**, **bar.php**, and **baz.php**, each `include`'d by the next, as follows:

**foo.php**

```
<?php

$missile_launch_codes = [
    'missileA' => '...',
    'missileB' => '...',
    'missileC' => '...'
];
```

**bar.php**

```
<?php

require('foo.php');

function try_to_launch($launch_code) {
    ...
}

function launch_missile($missile_name) {
    if (in_array($missile_name, $missile_launch_codes)) {
        return try_to_launch($missile_launch_codes[$missile_name]);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**baz.php**

```
require('bar.php')   

if (...) {
    launch_missile(...);
}
```

The file **baz.php** needs to be able to use `launch_missile()`, but it definitely shouldn't have access to `$missile_launch_codes`. How would I isolate the `$missile_launch_codes` imported from **foo.php** to keep them out of the hands of **baz.php**?

Comment: Have you ever heard about [Object oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)? In that, this concept is called `encapsulation`.

Answer (score 0):

What you can probably do is this [Object-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) way:

**Missile.php**

```
Class Missile
{

    private $missile_launch_codes = [
        'missileA' => '...',
        'missileB' => '...',
        'missileC' => '...'
    ];

    private function try_to_launch($launch_code) {
        ...
    }

    public function launch_missile($missile_name) {
        if (in_array($missile_name, $this->missile_launch_codes)) {
            return $this->try_to_launch($this->missile_launch_codes[$missile_name]);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

**Launch.php**

```
include('Missile.php');
Class Launch extends Missile
{
    if (...) {
        $this->launch_missile(...);
    }
}
```

Here, `$missile_launch_codes` can only be accessible to class `Missile` only as it is declared `private`.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, you need to make it in OOP. You can do it in this way...

foo.php:

```
class Foo {
    protected function missile_launch_codes() {
         return [
           'missileA' => '...',
           'missileB' => '...',
           'missileC' => '...'
         ];
    }
}
```

bar.php:

```
class Bar extends Foo {
   public function try_to_launch($launch_code) {
      ...
   }

   public function launch_missile($missile_name) {
      if (in_array($missile_name, $missile_launch_codes)) {
         return try_to_launch($this->missile_launch_codes[$missile_name]);
      } else {
         return false;
      }
   }
}
```

baz.php

```
class Baz extends Bar {
   // you cannot access missile_launch_codes() here
}
```

Try to research more about OOP to understand more what I am trying to say here..